# Jpa mapping table not deleting at constraint error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I would like to know why spring jpa isn't deleting the rows that are causing a constraint error or a way to make it possible to edit my Account entity with new roles.

The following entities are involved in the action i'm trying to perform.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
class AccountEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                    @Column(nullable = false) val email: String,
                    @Column(nullable = false) val password: String,
                    @OneToMany(
                            mappedBy = "accountUuid",
                            cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
                            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
                    ) val accountRolesEntity: List<AccountRolesEntity>) : BaseEntity(uuid)

@Entity
@Table(name = "account_roles")
class AccountRolesEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                         @Column(nullable = false) val accountUuid: UUID,
                         @OneToOne val role: RoleEntity) : BaseEntity(uuid)

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
class RoleEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                 @Column(nullable = false) val name: String ) : BaseEntity(uuid)
```

So i'm trying to update the roles of a specific account.

For example:
If X has roles '**viewer**' and '**editor**' and suppose i want to change it to **viewer** only.

I do the following steps:

1. Request account entity from database
2. set new accountRolesEntity (received from controller) to account
3. Call the jpa repository save method

Method in Service class:

```
fun updateExistingAccount(account: AccountDTO, adjustedRoles: List<RoleDTO>): AccountDTO {
    val mappedRoles: List<AccountRolesEntity> = adjustedRoles.map { accountRolesMapper.map(account.uuid, it) }
    val accountEntity = accountMapper.map(account, mappedRoles)
    return accountMapper.map(accountRepository.save(accountEntity))
}
```

The **error** i'm getting is: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_roles_account_uuid_role_uuid_key"**

This is because i have a constrain in my database to make sure that an account may **not** have duplicate roles. The create table statement is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE account_roles (
                               uuid         UUID PRIMARY KEY,
                               account_uuid UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES account(uuid),
                               role_uuid    UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES role(uuid),
                               UNIQUE (account_uuid, role_uuid)
);
```

There is a fix for this by performing all the actions 1 by 1: Delete first and then make new inserts. But there should be a better way for this.

Comment: Sounds like your insert is not occurring in a transaction.

Comment: My knowledge is limited, this is too complex to understand

Answer (score 0):

actually "AccountRolesEntity" is not an entity, it's a table which keeps the relationships of two entity by keeping **ids** of that entities into the table.

so for the first step, you should have something like this,

```
    @JoinTable(name = "account_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account")
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role"))
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountUuid",
              cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    val accountRolesEntity: List<AccountRolesEntity>) :BaseEntity(uuid)
```

and I think your problem depends on your **cascades** and your **class diagram** so check them again.